# Google Play Store Download/Install listener

Tags: android, google-play, listener

Is there a way or a listener with which I can see in real time which app has just been installed from the Google Play Store on my mobile phone?

I hope you can help me.

EDIT:
**Solution**

With the idea of JacksOnF1re I found another thread, which solved my problem.
[Link to the Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362639/how-to-use-implicit-broadcast-package-added-in-oreo-8-0)

Comment: unfortunately tou can't. But you can listen to the **app install** in general, not from google play specially

Answer (score 1):

Kind of. You can listen to application install broadcasts. You can declare those `BroadcastReceiver` in your `manifest`. Moreover you can check the source of install afterwards, using the PackageManager.

**Install source:** For that I would redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262979/android-install-source) stackoverflow answer.

The **broadcast** your are looking for is `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)

**1**. listen to `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` using `BroadcastReceiver`, containing the package name of the application

**2**. use package name to gather source of install, using the `package manager`

Comment: Not possible with Android 8 **I believe** https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions . I'm personally not sure if I understand this correctly.

Comment: Goof catch, but I would give it a try on the emulator

Comment: I tested it with the broadcast receiver. I had no problems with API 24. API 26 (Android 8) didn't work. But I didn't get an error message, and I didn't get a message about the installation.

Comment: I found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362639/how-to-use-implicit-broadcast-package-added-in-oreo-8-0