# BroadcastReceiver Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED/REMOVED Android Oreo

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcast

This is my broadcast receiver class and the implementation of it in main.

Problem is that `onReceive` method never gets called.

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
  override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
     Toast.makeText(p0, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     ......

     private var broadcastReceiver: MyBroadcastReceiver = MyBroadcastReceiver()

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            ......

            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter().apply {
                addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
                addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
            })
     }

     override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
     }
 }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the `BroadcastReceiver` needs a number of steps to be set up.

First of all did yout pass to the manifest the receiver?

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

***Edit***: Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996338/how-to-register-for-action-package-added-and-action-package-removed-on-android-o),  where is suggested ACTION_PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED or `JobScheduler`

try also to reinstall the app on the emulator

Comment: I tried to declare my broadcast receiver on manifest without luck. So I tried programmatically as you can see from the code I posted but still doesn't work

Comment: it looks as somebody had your problem and fixed adding data package into the manifest, now as you are possibly targeting oreo/26  you cannot use the manifest so should see if is possible to insert this command in your IntentFilter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-make-my-app-receive-broadcast-when-other-applications-are-installed-or-re

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to add data package programmatically

Answer (score 2):

I could make it work with the following code

```
class KotlinBroadcastReceiver(action: (context: Context, intent: Intent) -> Unit) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) = action(context, intent)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val broadcastReceiver = KotlinBroadcastReceiver { context, _ ->
        Toast.makeText(context, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)
            addDataScheme("package") // I could not find a constant for that :(
        })
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
    }
}
```