# Can I use Foreground Service to monitor new app installation by registering ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast dynamically in service for Oreo and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, foreground-service

I am successfully able to monitor new app installation by dynamically registering broadcast in foreground service for Oreo and above version. But for this I always have to show a persistent notification of my app.
Is there any alternative to

**Google in documentation says:**

*You should only use a foreground service when your app needs to perform a task that is noticeable by the user even when they're not directly interacting with the app. For this reason, foreground services must show a status bar notification with a priority of PRIORITY_LOW or higher, which helps ensure that the user is aware of what your app is doing. If the action is of low enough importance that you want to use a minimum-priority notification, you probably shouldn't be using a service; instead, consider using a scheduled job.*

So can I use foreground service for this purpose. If not than what is its alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the doc you posted, consider using a scheduled job.

if you use a foreground service you will need a constant notification and that would be annoying for the user (plus you don't install new package every five minutes so ...)

Instead you should schedule a job to check if a new package is installed.

Look at the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996338/how-to-register-for-action-package-added-and-action-package-removed-on-android-o)

> You can also use polling, setting up a JobScheduler job to check every so often, asking PackageManager for what has changed in the roster of installed apps via [getChangedPackages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getChangedPackages(int)).